# why are the integers from the array not converting?

Tags: c

The integers entered by the user are suppose to scanf each number in different conversions (%d, %i, %o, %u, %x), then printf in %d.
This is the output I am getting: 437 437 287 437 1079
I'am suppose to get: 437 437 665 437 1b5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LENGTH 5

int main()
{
int array[LENGTH];

printf("Enter the value 437 five times: ");
scanf("%d", &array[0]);
scanf("%i", &array[1]);
scanf("%o", &array[2]);
scanf("%u", &array[3]);
scanf("%x", &array[4]); 


printf("\nRead with %%d:");
printf("\n%d", array[0]);
printf(" %d", array[1]);
printf(" %d", array[2]);
printf(" %d", array[3]);
printf(" %d", array[4]); 


}
```

Comment: Why do you think that printing with `%d` will give you hex or octal output?

Comment: Prepend each `scanf` format string with a space

Comment: 437 in octal is 287 in decimal. Why should it be 665?

Comment: @GovindParmar that isn't necessary here, those specifiers all filter leading whitespace.

Comment: This isn't surprising. `0x437 == 1079` and `0437 == 287`

Comment: I think you have your input and output conversion formats round the wrong way.

Comment: With `%o`, the corresponding argument must be a pointer to unsigned int.  Since you are passing the address of an `int`, the behavior is undefined.  Similarly for `%i` and `%x`.

Answer (score 0):

For example the octal value `437` in decimal is equal to `4 * 8^2 + 3 * 8^2 + 7 * 8^0 = 256 + 24 + 7 = 287`.

That is if you use the conversion specifier `%o` then entered digits are interpreted as octal digits. The same is valid for the conversion specifier `%x` that is entered digits are interpreted as hexadecimal digits..

Comment: If I comment out the all printf and scanf except for scanf("%x", array[0]); and printf("%d", array[0]), I get the answer I want and thats the same for %o. I just think I'm doing something wrong with the array or with the format of scanf/printf